# How do I ensure that a click event is limited only to a card I have clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-cards

I am using two Bootstrap cards in my application. I conceal one of the cards (which is blue in colour) behind a card (which is white in colour) as illustrated below:

[image: An image of the blue card while concealed behind the white card]

...and use the following code to reveal the concealed blue card behind the white card:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".card-horizontal").click(function(){
            $(".backPanel").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
```

resulting in the **desired** below illustrated effect:

[image: An image showing the revealed concealed blue card]

The issue I am having here is that when I click on a card in order to reveal its blue concealed card, all blue concealed cards belonging to all-white cards get simultaneously revealed as illustrated below:

How do I modify the above code to limit this event to only the clicked cards?

Find below my code for the card:

```
<div class="card w-75 card-horizontal" id="nftCard">
    <div class="img-square-wrapper">
       <img class="nftImages" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body cardPadding">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card w-75 card-horizontal backPanel">
    <div class="img-square-wrapper">
        <div class="card-body ">
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the “ nftCard” you seem to have one closing </div> too many.

Comment: @SymboLinker Thanks for pointing it out. This has now been corrected, although this was a typo here in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You use `$(".card-horizontal")` to get elements by class name. You could give the cards and the backPanels their own `id` and use something like this for each pair:

```
$("#white-card1").on("click", function(){
    $("#blue-panel1").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Another way is to use things like parent, child, etc. to navigate the DOM.

In that case, if you like to use a class name, define a new class “white-card” for the click event. Otherwise clicking a blue card (in your code called a "backPanel") also does something.

If all those "white-card"s have the corresponding "backPanel" after them on the same level, the `nextElementSibling` property can be used.

Instead of using jQuery, I prefer pure JavaScript (except for the `slideDown` method that you need):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".white-card").forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", function(){
        el.nextElementSibling.slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

**I tested the following code in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net):**

*HTML*

```
<div class="my-clickable-class" style="background-color: blue;">x</div>
<div style="background-color: red;">x</div>

<div class="my-clickable-class" style="background-color: yellow;">x</div>
<div style="background-color: orange;">x</div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
document.querySelectorAll(".my-clickable-class").forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        el.style.color = 'white';
        el.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    });
});
```

- Clicking the blue `div` changes the color of the red `div`.
- Clicking the yellow `div` changes the color of the orange `div`.

Comment: You can also get the index of the card you've clicked (.card-horizontal) and specifies that same index on the code (something like $(".card-horizontal")[0]

Comment: @SymbolLinker I have updated my code by adding the HTML. Can you kindly show me in code?

Comment: @SirBT Now I have provided code that I tested. Excuse me for not providing a proper answer earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **each** whenever you click on an item it will search for the related element with the class **.backPanel** and slide it down

**In Case backPanel is a Children of Card element**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".card-horizontal").each(function(){
          $(this).on("click", function(){
              $(this).children(".backPanel").slideDown("slow");
          });
      });
 });
```

**In Case backPanel is a Sibling of Card element**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".card-horizontal").each(function(){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            $(this).siblings(".backPanel").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

**In case backPanel is an additional class in the Card element**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".card-horizontal").each(function(){
          $(this).on("click", function(){
              $(".backPanel", this).slideDown("slow");
          });
      });
 });
```

Comment: Your code snippet dosent seem to work. The backpanel doesn't slide down. Kindly review.

Comment: can you share your html code? @SirBT

Comment: @SirBT is the .backPanel a sibling or a children for your card element?

Comment: I have updated my question by adding the HTML code. Perhaps both the cards (the white and the blue cards) arent correctly represented in HTML code. Kindly advise

Comment: @SirBT I updated my solution check it out, i hope its help

Comment: I think your solution doesn't work because the blue .backpanel class is linked to a separate card which isnt a sibling nor a child of the white .card element... Kindly look at how the two separate cards are represented in my code and review. Perphaps you can advise on how to HTML code so that the blue .backpanel is coded as a child of the white .card?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243444/discussion-between-sirbt-and-mmh4all).

Comment: @SirBT try this **$(this).next().slideDown("slow");**

Comment: ` $(this).next().slideDown("slow");` does not work either

Answer (score 0):

If the `backPanel` is a child of `card-horizontal`, you can make use of the `this` keyword to only select the `backPanel` inside `card-horizontal`.

[Here's the documentation for this keyword.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".card-horizontal").click(function(){
            $(".backPanel", this).slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
```

**Edit:**

Since the `card-horizontal` and `backPanel` could be siblings according to your code. You can wrap them in a `div` and do this:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".card-horizontal").click(function(){
            $(this).siblings(".backPanel").slideDown("slow");
        });
   });
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have updated my question by adding the HTML code for both the white card .card-horizontal and the blue card .backPanel. I don't think I coded the .backPanel as a child of card-horizontal. Do you mind showing me how to do so?

Comment: Hey @SirBT, I've edited the answer.